# How to add toaster in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular7

Any idea how to add a toaster notification when an error occurs instead of using alert. Many tutorials out there just make a tutorial when clicking a button but I want some automatization. Below is my code

```
saveStudentDetails(values) {
  const studentData = {};

  studentData['id'] =  values.id;
  studentData['password'] =  values.password;
  this.crudService.loginstudent(studentData).subscribe(result => {
    this.student = result;
    this.router.navigate(['/address']);
  },
    err => {
      console.log('status code ->' + err.status);
      alert('Please try again');
 });
```

}

Any idea how can i make an error toaster notification base on this code? Thank you

Comment: If you have not implemented third party design library yet you can use https://material.angular.io/components/snack-bar/overview it contains lot of usefull stuff

Comment: aww, I already used MDBoostrap but in the documentation, I still need to press the button in order to make the notification pop up. Do you have any idea how to make its appearance only when an error occurs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For display toaster use [ngx-toastr](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-toastr) library

Steps:

1) `npm install ngx-toastr --save`

2) Follow other setups from [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-toastr#setup)

Quick Code :

```
import { ToastrService } from 'ngx-toastr';

constructor(private toastr: ToastrService) {}

saveStudentDetails(values) {
  const studentData = {};

  studentData['id'] =  values.id;
  studentData['password'] =  values.password;
  this.crudService.loginstudent(studentData).subscribe(result => {
    this.student = result;
    this.router.navigate(['/address']);
  },
    err => {
      console.log('status code ->' + err.status);
      this.toastr.error('Hello world!', 'Toastr fun!');
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use any third-party toaster packages like [ngx-toastr](https://github.com/scttcper/ngx-toastr) to display an error toaster notification.

For example with ngx-toastr:

```
constructor(
  ...
  private toastr: ToastrService
) {}

this.crudService.loginstudent(studentData).subscribe(
  result => {
    this.student = result;
    this.router.navigate(['/address']);

    this. toastr.success('Logged in');
  },
  err => {
    console.log('status code ->' + err.status);

    this. toastr.error('Please try again');
  }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use toastr. More information can be found at https://www.npmjs.com/package/toastr. The demo is at https://codeseven.github.io/toastr/demo.html